# Im using very large data. And my app crashes. I need a solution that dont consumes a lot of memory and its still fast

Tags: java, android

So, im using android studio to develop and app, and the most important data, have arrays with like 100 000 objects. What should i use to store this data. I get this data from a get request when user logs in. And i need to store that that while user is on the app.
Ive tried using a global variable and then i tried with bundle&serializable. Booth didnt work, i had a problem out of memory.

What should i use instead ?

My object type is somethin like this, and i need to store up to 200 000 of them.

```
String ID;
String Name;
String PVM;
String FinalName;
String SN;
Defect defect;
```

where defect is another class object.

Comment: do you really need the whole data set at any time?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by pulling such a huge data at single shot?

Comment: yes, the data is information from modules wich i display in a map @PradeepSimha

Comment: @jhamon yes, i really need all this data

Comment: The app was running just fine, but with the features added, is now very heavy and running out of memory too many times.

Comment: Even if you need it in memory: do you need *all* those fields from *all* objects at once? Can you reduce the amount of stuff you need accessible at all time and only load (from disk/local db) the details when you need them?

Comment: @JoachimSauer i need all of them, because all that fields needs to be displayed when the user clicks on a feature on the map. And for me dont seems like an option to make a request from API every time i need this info. I think best way is to store something internaly

Comment: That means you need all fields **when the user clicks on it**. And I didn't suggest re-requesting from the API, but from some local storage: i.e. store the result of the API locally, keep *parts* of it (that which you need to display the features on the map) in memory and load the remaining details from disk when the user clicks.

Comment: As you stated, a map needs to include these data.

As a result, I would like to recommend that you reduce the amount of data based on the size of the map, such as 1 metre, 10 metres, 100 metres, or 1 km, etc. Determine the area that will be displayed on the map first. At runtime, you can collect additional data from the background using various methods, such as threading.

Comment: @JoachimSauer oh sry, i didnt understand you as i should. I can read that information from a JSON file. Is it a good way ? store a JSON file in raw data, and then i can update it and read it when i need ?

Comment: @FranciscoTorres Yes, you can read and update that JSON file at run time. You can use `GSON` for that it will make easier.

Comment: @FranciscoTorres Can you please update the data size?

Comment: @AndyBoy Update data size where ? I didnt get the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250551/discussion-between-andyboy-and-francisco-torres).

Answer (score 0):

Room Database is what you want, it is sqlite underneath, and very simple to use.

```
@Entity
data class MyModel(
@PrimaryKey
val ID: String,
val name: String,.....) {

@Dao
interface DaoMyModel {
//You put all methods to handle data here
// Some examples

@Insert
fun insertOne(item: MyModel)
@Insert
fun insertMultiple(items: List<MyModel>)

//Get all
@Query("SELECT * FROM MyModel")
fun getAll() : List<MyModel>

//Observe all with kotlin Flow
@Query("SELECT * FROM MyModel")
fun flowAll() : Flow<List<MyModel>>

}
} 


//Your database class
@Database(entities = [MyModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase: RoomDatabase(){
abstract fun getMyModelDao() : MyModel.DaoMyModel

}

//Db Init

fun provideDatabase(applicationContext: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext, MyDb::class.java , "MyDatabaseName")
        .build()



//handling the data

//get the database
val myDatabase = provideDatabase(context)
//get dao
val myModelDao = myDatabase.getMyModelDao()

//insert new item
myModelDao.insert(model)
```

I would suggest that you go tho with this 1 hour codelab tutorial
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0